# ubuntu 20.04 wired network setting is missing

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-20.04

I have Ubuntu 20.04 on VMWare. recently I cant connect to internet And I don't know why. 
I tried `sudo lshw -C network` and the result was `*-network DISABLED ...` so I used `sudo ip link set {logical name} up`. after that network status changed to `*-network ...`. but yet no internet. so I restart the VM and after that the network status was `*-network DISABLED ...`. please help.

Comment: If you found a solution, it is best if you post that as an answer and mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: Please copy your update section into an answer and self-accept as it has solved your issue

Answer (score 32, accepted):

it seems there is bug about this issue and it is common. by the following the wired network setting returned.
`$ sudo nmcli networking off`
`$ sudo nmcli networking on`
no other network reset commands worked for me and only these ones worked in my case. and yet there was another problem. I had no IP at all! no dynamic and no static. so manually I set a static IP and could get back online.

Comment: Finally! Just lost few hours searching for this answer. Thanks.

Comment: I'm glad this helped you.

Comment: Thank you very much, It's a perfect solution.

Comment: wow never would have guessed this one.

Comment: Finally. perfect answer.

Comment: I have the same problem but unfortunately this did not solve it. (Well not exactly the same: 
$ifconfig
docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
        ether 02:42:ce:34:e6:4e  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

Comment: lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 23784  bytes 2711203 (2.7 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 23784  bytes 2711203 (2.7 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

Comment: wlp0s20f3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 129.104.107.227  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 129.104.107.255
        inet6 fe80::5727:c7c6:79ce:d6f3  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether dc:41:a9:a9:eb:e2  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 214538  bytes 230570417 (230.5 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 110262  bytes 39170210 (39.1 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

Comment: I just had this issue in Ubuntu 18.04 and this solution thankfully solved it as I was thinking about a reinstall. Due to my laptop dying, I hadn't turned on this machine in at least 9 months, so I'm not sure if that has anything to do with the bug showing up or not. However, it seems like a ridiculous issue all the way around.

Comment: That worked like a magic, thanks a lot..